# Facebook Js FB.ui how can I change the message parameter?

Tags: facebook, facebook-ui

```
var obj = {
 method: 'feed',
 link: mylinkt,
 picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
 name: 'Poonkt.us - My new Quote!',
 message: 'Test?', //<<--cant I access this?
 description: desc
};

FB.ui(obj);
```

Is there any possibility I can change the Facebook feed dialog's message parameter?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want to change to

Comment: @Satya, Anything basically, I just want to have some values already present in the message box (editable) in the dialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Message` is not a parameter according to the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) and it does even show up during the feed

Using api you cannot have a default value in message box

[DEMO](https://apps.facebook.com/fbrelll/saved/cfe42246d6f3fc302c60ae10c80c7263) (the demo is to say that even with a message parameter the feed does not contain any message)

Hope this helps

Comment: You can't do something for this, Facebook deprecated the message parameter on July 12th.